# How to make database parameter configurable in java web application?

Tags: java, web-applications

Hi all following is my database connection file,

```
package org.slingemp.common;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;

public class JDBCManager {

    public Connection mysqlConnection()  {
        Connection dbConnection = null;
        try {

          Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
          dbConnection=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/slingemp","root","root");
          //System.out.println("mysql Driver Connedted::::::::");

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return dbConnection;

    }
}
```

in this i want to make connection string and driver name configurable. how to do this and where to put the file which contains configurable values?

Regards
Tony

Comment: Have you looked into using JNDI?  I think that would be "standard" answer.  Also, having your application connect as root is not advisable.

Comment: Thanks for the valuable point, i am using tomcat 7. is it possible to use JNDI, i am sorry i have used JNDI in jboss before so that i've asked this question

Comment: Yes, JNDI can be used with tomcat 7.  See http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/jndi-datasource-examples-howto.html  This actually includes a step-by-step example for MySQL.

Comment: Thanks for patience and your valuable answers, how to do the following part in java not using jstl . 4. Test code of the reference you gave. Please do pardon me and spend some time

Comment: See step 3 of the Oracle example immediately following the MySQL example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put them into `.properties` file or server JNDI resources.

jdbc.properties example:

```
jdbc.driverClassName=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
jdbc.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/yourDatabaseName
jdbc.username=username
jdbc.password=password
```

Then in java class use this to get properties:

```
public static ResourceBundle getJdbcBundle() {
    return ResourceBundle.getBundle("jdbc");
}

String url = SomeClass.getJdbcBundle().getString("jdbc.url");
```

But more efficient way would be to use JNDI.

Answer (score 2):

You can place these values in a properties file say `database.properties` file, then load those properties by using a code like below:

```
private void loadProperties(){
  InputStream inputStream = JDBCManager.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("database.properties");
  try {
            databaseProperties.load(inputStream); // database properties is an instance variable Properties databaseProperties;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            logger.error("Exception occurred while loading server properties", e);
        }
}
```

As per comments:

Yes, JNDI can be used in Tomcat, for configuring datasource on Tomcat 7 please read this [official documentation](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/jndi-datasource-examples-howto.html)